# How do I display fields in the first 4 rows using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So I am using ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) and I would like to display the first four rows. Although I have 20 rows in all I only need to display the fields in the first five rows or the last 5 rows

Also, my code doesn't need to be in a loop so I am open to any answer. I only placed my code in a loop because it's the only way that I know how to display repeater sub fields. I am pretty new to using ACF fields

```
<?php

    // check if the repeater field has rows of data

    if( have_rows('repeat_field') ):

      // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('repeat_field') ) : the_row();

            // display a sub field value

              the_sub_field('place_name');
              the_sub_field('place_date');
              the_sub_field('place_time');


        endwhile;

    else :

        // no rows found

    endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stop the loop after finishing the number of runs you would like:

```
if( have_rows('repeat_field') ):

    $i=0; // Counter to keep track of number of runs

    while ( have_rows('repeat_field') ) : the_row();
            the_sub_field('place_name');
            the_sub_field('place_date');
            the_sub_field('place_time');

            $i++; // Increase the number by one after each run
            if($i==4) break; // Stop after four runs

    endwhile;
endif;
```